# What is the actual name of Codility's Caterpillar method?

Tags: algorithm

Codality has a funny way of naming things. Like for example: Instead of Majority Element they say "Leader".

There is a technique they describe [here](https://codility.com/media/train/13-CaterpillarMethod.pdf) called [Caterpillar method.](https://codility.com/media/train/13-CaterpillarMethod.pdf) What is the real technical name for this technique? (I guessed Backtracking, but I don't think so)

I am asking since I would like to read more about it other than the limited introduction provided by Codality.

Comment: sliding window?

Comment: No. I think, the 2 pointer method is the generic method name. It fits with all the examples and sample problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds closer to the general method of two pointers. I don't think there's a proper name for it, but that's what I've heard it called most frequently. Further examples of its usage can be found on various interview prep sites, such as [this one](https://leetcode.com/articles/two-pointer-technique/), as it's a common basis for a number of interview questions.

The triangle problem Codility posits can also be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-triangles-possible/) with more discussion.